# When are singletons guaranteed to be so?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Suppose you have a Node package `thing` that defines

```
var theThing = {}
exports.theThing = theThing
```

Package `consumer` does this:

```
var thing1 = require('thing')
var thing2 = require('thing')
assert(thing1.theThing === thing2.theThing)
```

This appears to pass a quick test. Presumably when Node executes the second `require`, it notices `thing` is already instantiated, and quietly returns a pointer to the existing instance?

Now suppose the following happens:

- Two versions of `thing` are published on npm, 1.0.0 and 2.0.0.
- Two packages, `consumer1` and `consumer2`, are published on npm; they have dependencies on versions 1.0.0 and 2.0.0 respectively of `thing`, and each re-exports `theThing`.
- Another packager `endConsumer` has dependency on `consumer1` and `consumer2`.

So if `endConsumer` tries this test:

```
assert(consumer1.theThing === consumer2.theThing)
```

That must fail, right? At this point, Node cannot reuse one instance of `thing` because two distinct versions of the package are required?

I would guess you should end up being able to rely on a singleton being unique everywhere in a process, if and only if all transitive dependencies on the package exporting that singleton, are on the exact same version of that package. But is that guess correct, or is the actual rule something else?

Comment: Yes, that will fail, and helps demonstrate why singletons are a terrible idea.

Comment: @Ryan Indeed, I was coming to the conclusion that relying on singletons would be a terrible idea because then a program would quietly break if one package updates a dependency and another doesn't. Figured I'd better try to understand the actual rule before making a decision, though.

Comment: This is indeed a great example of the problem with singletons that are exacerbated by the sloppy way that npm resolves version conflicts. That said, as @Ryan points out, singletons are bad anyway.

Comment: @AluanHaddad 'sloppy way that npm resolves version conflicts' - what do you mean?

Comment: by using file system recursion that duplicates dependencies but in a non-obvious way. Just my opinion

Comment: I'd imagine singletons make sense most for specialized unique cases of an app. When developing a package that will be utilized as a dependency for other packages, it is poor design for the reason op stated (and several others), but for a standalone project, that will never be depended on, singletons are really not a poor decision and help reveal the benefits of said design pattern.

Comment: @zillaofthegods perhaps, but I really prefer to reduce state as much as possible. Sometimes, a stateful singleton is necessary but in that case it should not be left to npm and the NodeJS require function to manage it via module load caching.

Comment: I definitely agree with the not leaving it up to npm (terrible dependency management as you mentioned). Curious though, I'd like to know your objections towards stateful"ness"? I don't necessarily disagree, just curious.

Comment: Probably not the best venue for that discussion. I just generally like to reduce all mutable state as much as possible because it makes it easier to read and reason about the code. Like if you don't reassign to local, using `const` allows the reader to never even have to think about it. Of course state is indeed necessary in many situations. I appreciate the discussion by the way! Also, I drink FP® Kool-Aid.